# Extracting values from one of multiple PRISM rasters in R for date

Tags: r, raster

I have tried to follow the code from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63237565/extracting-values-from-one-of-multiple-prism-rasters-in-r][1] but I keep running into multiple errors.  I am also trying to extra daily precipitation rather than monthly temperature.

```
dates <-  seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2019-12-31"), by="days")

library(prism)

for (d in unique(dates)) {
  dir.create(d, FALSE)
  options(prism.path = d)
  get_prism_dailys(type = "ppt", dates = d) 
}

#Error in dir.create(d, FALSE) : invalid 'path' argument

locs <- foo.df[,5:4]
head(locs)
length(locs)

locs$Longitude<-as.numeric(locs$Longitude)
locs$Latitude<-as.numeric(locs$Latitude)

#Keep things simple and put the results in a list first
temps <- list()
for(i in 1:length(dates)) {
  options(prism.path = dates[i])
  climate_data <- prism_stack(ls_prism_data()) 
  temps[[i]] <- extract(climate_data, locs)
}

#Error in list.files(getOption("prism.path")) : invalid 'path' argument
#In addition: Warning messages:
#  1: 'prism_stack' is deprecated.
#Use '`pd_stack()`' instead.
#See help("Deprecated") 
#2: 'ls_prism_data' is deprecated.
#Use '`prism_archive_ls()`' instead.
#See help("Deprecated")
```

I'm not sure what I need to change to a) make this code work for days vs years and b) how to convert this script from the deprecated code to the newest code.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go step by step.

```r
library(prism)
#> Be sure to set the download folder using `prism_set_dl_dir()`.
dates <-  seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2019-01-02"), by="days")
unique(dates)
#> [1] "2019-01-01" "2019-01-02"
```

Till now everything is fine.

```
for (d in unique(dates)) {
  dir.create(d, FALSE)
  options(prism.path = d)
  get_prism_dailys(type = "ppt", dates = d) 
}

#Error in dir.create(d, FALSE) : invalid 'path' argument
```

Why?? Let's see what's wrong:

```r
for (d in unique(dates)) {
  print(d)
}

#> [1] 17897
#> [1] 17898
```

Ah, `d in dates` is converted to `integer`, and `dir.create()` expects an `character`. Let's change it providing the dates `as.character`:

```r
for (d in 1:length(dates)) {
  dir.create(as.character(dates[d]), TRUE)
  options(prism.path = as.character(dates[d]))
  get_prism_dailys(type = "ppt", dates = dates[d]) 
}
#>   |   0%  |
     |======================================================================| 100%
#>   |   0%  |
     |======================================================================| 100%
```

Seems data was downloaded; to be sure we can check it right now:

```r
list.files(as.character(dates[1]))
#> [1] "PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmD2_20190101_bil"    
#> [2] "PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmD2_20190101_bil.zip"
```

As you haven's shared details of `foo.df`` I will skip this part:

```r
locs <- foo.df[,5:4]
head(locs)
length(locs)

locs$Longitude<-as.numeric(locs$Longitude)
locs$Latitude<-as.numeric(locs$Latitude)
```

The rest is pretty simple: below error is the same as previous, `path` has to be `character`

```r
#Error in list.files(getOption("prism.path")) : invalid 'path' argument
```

So, let's supply `as.character` as needed. The deprecated function should be replaced by the new ones, like:

```r
#Keep things simple and put the results in a list first
temps <- list()
for(i in 1:length(dates)) {
  options(prism.path = as.character(dates[i]))
  climate_data <- pd_stack(prism_archive_ls()) 
  temps[[i]] <- extract(climate_data, locs)
}
```

Regards,
Grzegorz

Comment: Grzegorz, thank you so much that worked perfectly.  I really appreciate your explanations so that now I can tweak future code. cheers, Amanda